# Include site name in KnowledgeArticleViewStat Report?

Tags: reporting, force.com-sites, articles

We have multiple sites that host FAQ/PKB pages that show Articles. Some of these Articles are displayed on one or more of the sites.

It's possible to report on view stats using the KnowledgeArticleViewStat object:
https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleviewstat.htm

However does anyone know if it is possible to include the name of the site the Article was viewed through/on?

Comment: This is great question :)

Comment: looks like no ways atleast when i see docs and resources

Comment: Yeah that's what I had found so far as well...I'm going to experiment with data categories and see if I can contrive something from them.